# Script to associate an extension to a program

Tags: file, registry, batch-file, openoffice.org, scripting

My customer is replacing MS Office with OpenOffice in some workstations. My program export a file to Excel using the .xml extension (using open format) and opens it using the current associated program (using ShellExecute)

The problem is that OpenOffice does not register the .xml extension associated with it.

Manually association works fine, but I want to make a .reg or something to easily change the setting.

I'm looking in the registry in a PC with the change already made, but the

```
"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xml"
```

key does not have anything referencing OpenOffice.

Where is the association stored? How can I make a script to do the work?

Comment: Take a look at https://superuser.com/q/406985/8271

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The real association is stored in the key that `"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xml"` points to.

On my machine, the default value of that key says `"xmlfile"`, most likely that is the same for yours.

So let's go to `"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile"`. There you can see (and change) what command is going to be used to launch that type of file:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\shell\open\command
```

Windows uses this kind of redirection to map multiple file extensions to the same file type, and thus to the same application.

Under `"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\shell"` there are multiple sub-keys that resemble the "verbs" of what you can do to the file. Again, the default value of the `"shell"` key decides which of these verbs is used if you double click the file. In my case this is `"open"`.

**Conclusion:**

With that knowledge, the easiest way to make an association scriptable is to use regedit to export a .reg file containing that change, and apply it to the target computer with a double click or:

```
regedit /s new_xml_association.reg
```

or (if you are on XP or higher and know what you do) overwrite the current value with:

```
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\shell\open\command" /ve /d "path\to\program %1"
```

At any rate, a deeper look into `reg add/?` command is advised. The first solution is safer.

Comment: In my pc this key points to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12\MSOXMLED.EXE" /verb open "%1" But maybe this .exe then open the OpenOffice calc app.

Comment: It should be the OpenOffice Calc app, if you want to launch that. "MSOXMLED.EXE" really is the MS Office XML editor that comes with InfoPath

Comment: Not sure if this is the key. If I delete it, the doble click still works.

Comment: Hi!
I used [SharpShell](https://sharpshell.codeplex.com) and created an item in explorer context menu and when I (user) right click on some song files and click on my added item those files will add to my music player. now i want to do it by double-clicking (opening,press enter )files too. how can i do it? do you know? can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

consider the dos command `assoc`:

> C:>assoc /?
>   Displays or modifies file extension
>   associations
>
> ASSOC [.ext[=[fileType]]]
>
> .ext      Specifies the file
>   extension to associate the file type
>   with   fileType  Specifies the file
>   type to associate with the file
>   extension
>
> Type ASSOC without parameters to
>   display the current file associations.
>   If ASSOC is invoked with just a file
>   extension, it displays the current
>   file association for that file
>   extension.  Specify nothing for the
>   file type and the command will delete
>   the association for the file
>   extension.

Comment: Can assoc also change the associated application? Has it been there always or is it new to XP or something? It's at least new to me...

Comment: "Assoc .xml" returns ".xml=xmlfile"
"Assoc xmlfile" returns "xmlfile=XML Document"
Can't go further because Assoc do not accept the space

Comment: @Eduardo You should be able to quote the space.

Answer (score 1):

Using file associations in this case seems like the wrong thing to do. *You* want your application to open the file in OpenOffice but what if your user wants to leave the file association for XML files untouched? What if something else on their system also relies on that association? You are breaking their system in that case. If you are the IT person then perhaps that is OK (still questionable programming practice), but if not then this is a bad thing to do.

Use the OpenOffice COM implementation to open the file instead.

Good simple example here:
http://www.kalitech.fr/clients/doc/VB_APIOOo_en.html

Answer (score -1):

I just came across this whilst searching for the same answer. I found a better solution using the Windows FindExecutable API, that can be used from C# using PInvoke.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.findexecutable

Comment: On further investigation it's better to use AssocQueryString which doesn't require a phyisical file for the lookup:http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi/AssocQueryString.html