# Ask and use user input

Tags: powershell, input

I am trying to make a script that will prompt the user for their computer name, then use that info in a `Get-EventLog` line. I am new to powershell and I use to do it with batch scripts however I am not sure how to do it here.

This is what I have so far:

```
$name1 = Read-Host 'Enter name'
cls
Get-EventLog system -computername COMPUTERNAMEHERE -InstanceId 2147489657 -Newest 5 | ft EventID,TimeWritten,MachineName -AutoSize
Pause
```

Also... how do would I make this run by double clicking on it like you would with a batch script?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something...are you just asking how to use the value you read into **$name1** as the argument to the **-ComputerName** paramater? Just replace `COMPUTERNAMEHERE` with the variable, **$name1**.

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-any-way-to-make-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-ps1-file) about double-clicking and powershell.

Comment: That's all you do? Now I feel dumb.

Comment: It runs but if I try to run it with the shortcut I get an error:
cannot be loaded because running scripts is 
disabled on this system. Do you know what I can add in the script to run this without turning off restriction completely? Just for this script.

Comment: @Aaron You configure your Execution Policy.  See [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849821.aspx) and [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx).

Comment: Yes I saw that but is there a way to only run it for that script while having it Restricted at any other time?

Comment: You can also call the PowerShell interpreter directly, telling it to use Bypass for the current file only: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File <script_name>`

Comment: I created a shortcut with that and it works fine ty.

Answer (score 1):

Not really answering your first question, as you seem to have that covered,  Regarding the error that you get about disabled scripts: By default and design, Microsoft closed a major attack vector that was present in all it's previous scripting attempts: the arbitrary execution of code.  You will need to look into [Execution Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847748.aspx) to learn more, but basically, out of the box, PowerShell only allows line by line execution from a command host.

@jscott is right that the `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` parameter to the PowerShell exe will work for you, but I would recommend you understand the implications of the Bypass execution policy if you use this all over the place.

My favorite policy for trusted machines is the `RemoteSigned` policy.  It gives you a measure of security against arbitrary execution (any script not originating on your machine needs to be cryptographically signed by trusted certificate) and still allows you to run scripts.

Comment: But there is something I can run just for that script that will allow it work while it runs and thats it?