# Run file with Powershell

Tags: file, powershell

I have a ps1 file that is opened by default with Notepad.
If I right click this file and choose **Run with Powershell**, the commands inside the file are correctly run.

But I would like `Powershell` to be the default program to `run` (not "open") this file. So, if I just right click the file, then **open with**, then **choose default program** and choose `Windows Powershell`, this is not enough, because the commands are not run. In this way, the file is just "opened", the Powershell windows opens and then disappears after a second.

How could I set `Powershell` to be the default program to RUN `.ps1` files, or at least one particular `.ps1` file?

Comment: I answered once this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10137504/608772)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some registry bits to help out.

Double click - runs .ps1

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" \"-file\" \"%1\""
```

Double Click 'Opens' via Notepad.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe\" \"%1\""
```

This is assuming you are not using any powershell specific IDE (such as powerGUI or Sapien) which are known to alter the default .ps1 action and would require additional settings to make this work.