# Double click ps1 file and powershell window disappears

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I checked here and there are some topics are talking about double clikc ps1 file to run. 
but my situation is that I have a ps1 file opening a remote session like this:

```
$pw = convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String xxxxxx
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "xxxx\admin",$pw
$pc = Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter PC name"
$session = new-pssession -computername $pc -credential $cred
Enter-PSSession $session
```

and i tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-any-way-to-make-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-ps1-file) to make it double click run,

```
powershell.exe -command "& 'C:\A path with spaces\MyScript.ps1' -MyArguments blah"
```

after I entered the pc name, the console disappears....

any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try it with the -NoExit option?

```
powershell.exe -NoExit -command "& 'C:\A path with spaces\MyScript.ps1' -MyArguments blah"
```

Comment: thanks, it works with -noexit option. didnt know there is a -noexit option lol

Answer (score 0):

This page provides a batch script (and additional info) making the process quite easy for having this no-exit behavior (and a fix for when the path has spaces) when launching from Windows Explorer: http://blog.danskingdom.com/fix-problem-where-windows-powershell-cannot-run-script-whose-path-contains-spaces