# assoc and ftype do not work under Powershell

Tags: powershell

I thought all cmd commands work the same under Powershell. For example `assoc` and `ftype` do not work. Is there a way to make them work instead of switching to `cmd` again?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Oh, they'll work, but you have to call them through cmd.exe as they're not actual programs that reside on disk, but functionality built-in to cmd.exe like so:

cmd /c assoc
cmd /c ftype

Comment: While this is perfectly workable, is there no way to do this in Powershell directly?

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573068), here's how to make `assoc` and `ftype` "just work" in powershell.

Add this to your [powershell profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/how-to-use-profiles-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6) -- you can just run `$Profile` in powershell to find your profile file:

```bsh
function assoc { cmd /c assoc $args }
function ftype { cmd /c ftype $args }
```

Answer (score 0):

stuff offered in these answers will not work ofc.
you need

```cpp
cmd /c assoc .="zzzfile"
cmd /c  --% ftype zzzfile="C:\Program Files\Sublime Text\sublime_text.exe" "%1"
```

without spaces.
this is from another answer on some thread on stackoverflow