# Powershell script making swf extension open with internet explorer

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how to write a powershell script that will set all .swf extensions to open up on Internet Explorer. I was trying to do this with a command prompt similar to the example below. Unfornately my boss is requiring this to be done through powershell. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated since I have a txt file that will loop through about 400 computers and need to make these changes on.

**CMD Way**

```
C:\>ASSOC .swf
.swf=ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash
C:\>FTYPE ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash
ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash="C:\bin\FlashPlayer.exe" %1
```

**What I am Trying:**

```
    Function Get-FileName{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [String]$Filter = "|*.*",
        [String]$InitialDirectory = "C:\")

        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
        $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
        $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
        $OpenFileDialog.filter = $Filter
        [void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
        $OpenFileDialog.filename
    }

    $file = Get-FileName -InitialDirectory $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Filter "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    ForEach ($item in (Get-Content $file)) {
        $sitem = $item.Split("|")
        $computer = $sitem[0].Trim()
        $user = $sitem[1].Trim()

    cmd /c assoc .swf=InternetExplorer.Application

        ### Will the above line automatically install on every pc? ###

    }
```

Any help with trying to insert how to change the FTYPE in powershell so that $computer can cycle through would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571900/assoc-and-ftype-do-not-work-under-powershell  should point you in the right direction. FTYPE is a command available to cmd.exe not something you can call. You could set a variable to the command and then call the variable.

Comment: This really seems like something that should be done with GPO instead of a script.

Comment: @Eris I wish I could but unfortunately there making me push this out through powershell. I tried editing the script any ideas of how I can fix it?

Comment: @Bob007 Does it look right in my script I edited?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Retrieve the value?  Set the command to run?  Please edit your question to make it clear exactly what you would do in cmd?  The "CMD way" code you've posted just prints the current value to the console and doesn't change anything.  Assuming you're not capturing that console output, you can replace this with a script zero lines long that does the same thing.

Comment: I am trying to make it that any swf extension will open in internet explorer

Comment: That's a different question from the one you asked originally.  See Powershell Remoting and [Invoke-Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx)

Comment: isnt that what im trying in my example?

Comment: In your question you are asking how to change settings on one computer.  How to do something on multiple remote computers is a different question.

Comment: Any help with this would be greatly appreciated since I have a txt file that will loop through about 400 computers and need to make these changes on. --- Here I ask how to do a loop through about 400 computers and I have an example of a ForEach

Comment: Short answer: `$comps="computername1","computername2",etc; Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comps { cmd /c assoc .swf=InternetExplorer.Application }`.  Longer answer here: http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/ .  Look up PowerShell Remoting and familiarize yourself with the concepts.  If you have a specific question about that, then go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: `{ cmd /c assoc .swf=InternetExplorer.Application }
[ComputerName] Connecting to remote server ComputerName failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the 
destination is running and is accepting requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM.` :( its on a domain ughhh why is this so difficult for me to grasp :(

Comment: @RyanBemrose Hey its not changing the file association? I tried adding the ftype after that and it still does not work either

Comment: I tried 
$comps="it-tech";
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comps { 
cmd /c assoc .swf
cmd /c ftype .swf=InternetExplorer.Application
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125108/discussion-between-david-brierton-and-ryan-bemrose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ASSOC` and `FTYPE` are CMD.exe built-in commands, not executables, which means they can only be run in the context of CMD.  The easiest way to run them is to [invoke CMD from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573068/821878).

```
cmd /c assoc .swf
cmd /c ftype ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash
```

If you need a "pure" PowerShell implementation, then you need to go to the registry.  `ASSOC` and `FTYPE` merely write to the registry under the`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` hive.  PowerShell does not have a default PSDrive for `HKCR:`, but that hive is also accessible under `HKLM:\Software\Classes`.

```
$ext = '.swf'
$HKCR = 'HKLM:\Software\Classes'

$ftype = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$HKCR\$ext" | select -expand '(default)'

$commandLine = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$HKCR\$ftype\shell\open" | select -expand '(default)'

$commandLine
```

To update these values, you simply use `Set-ItemProperty` on the same path.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "$HKCR\$ext" -Name '(default)' -Value 'ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash'
```

This requires you to run with Admin privileges.  This also assumes that the key already exists.  If not, you will have to create it with `New-Item`

```
if (-not (Test-Path "$HKCR\$ext")) {
    New-Item -Path "$HKCR\$ext"
}
```

---

**However**, if all you want to do is set `.swf` files to open in `iexplore.exe`, then retrieving the values is unnecessary, as is modifying the `FTYPE` key.  You need only change the extension association to `InternetExplorer.Application` instead of `ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash`.  The following full scripts will do this:

In Batch file:

```
assoc .swf=InternetExplorer.Application
```

In PowerShell:

```
cmd /c assoc .swf=InternetExplorer.Application
```

In "pure" PowerShell, by modifying the registry:

```
$key = "HKLM:\Software\Classes\.swf"
$defaultName = '(default)'
$newValue = 'InternetExplorer.Application'

if (-not (Test-Path $key)) {
    New-Item -Path $key
}
Set-Itemproperty -Path $key -Name $defaultName -Value $newValue
```

Note that modifying the registry doesn't take effect immediately.  You need to also send a WM_SETTINGCHANGE event, or simply restart explorer.exe (eg: by logging off).  You can find code to send the event [here](http://poshcode.org/2049), but usually this isn't a problem for automated scripts because they force the user to re-login anyway.

Comment: can you check the script I just edited is that what your talking about?

Comment: i want to use the cmd /c assoc you have but how do i have it loop through all the pcs to make it do all of them remotely?

Comment: i understand `cmd /c assoc .swf=InternetExplorer.Application` just trying to figure out how to do it on a list of computernames in my txt file

Comment: I edited the script from my question how does that cmd line know to do it on each of those pcs? do i need to add $computer in that line any where?