# Set default application for .ps1 files as powershell.exe

Tags: windows, powershell

I need to set default application for any powershell files as C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe using a powershell script. For that purpose I have written the following code -

```
cmd.exe /c assoc .ps1=
cmd.exe /c ftype myext="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
cmd.exe /c assoc .ps1=myext
```

Now, when I double click any .ps1 files, it opens a blank powershell window.

Can anyone please help me regarding this ?

Thanks!

Comment: `ftype myext="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe ""-File %1"""`

Comment: Although having script files execute by default is a pretty terrible idea

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. This code is not throwing any error, but it is opening the .ps1 file in notepad.exe by default.  When I check with assoc command it is showing .ps1=myext .

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10137504/608772) answer.

Comment: Changing default value for "HKCR:\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command" to '"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noLogo -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -file "%1"' did the trick. Thanks All!