# Powershell scripts doesnt work when running from specific folder

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I have a simple script which only prints "hello" to the screen.

When I run it from my desktop (for example) - it's working

When I run it from a specific folder under, `c:\specific_folder` it opens the "How do you want to open this file" window and even after I choose "Windows Powershell" it just keep popping up and script never executed..

I'm using Powershell version 5.1 
I checked the permissions on folder properties and give everyone a full control but no change..

EDIT:
the script is:

```
Write-output "Hello"
pause
```

I run it by double clicking it (manually).

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Can you include the script & how are you trying to run it?

Comment: @GarethLyons - done.

Comment: right click select "open with", "choose another App", select Powershell, Check "Always use this app to open PS1 files", Click OK. Also add a pause in the script so it keeps the window open

Comment: @ArcSet That's a very bad practice and also requires changing executionpolicy.

Comment: Some discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-any-way-to-make-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-ps1-file

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I agree but thats what he asked for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to make powershell script work by double clicking .ps1 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-any-way-to-make-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-ps1-file)

Comment: @ArcSet this isn't the case, I know hot to make it use the powershell as default but for some reason it isnt working in a specific directory, I think it is some permission related issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are double clicking it, it might be executing and instantly closing as the script has finished.

You might want to add something like read-host or sleep(1) to the end just to be able to confirm the script is working

Comment: This is not the problem, I added a `pause` just to make sure.. If I try to run in 2 different folders (by double clicking it) then in one folder it works and in the second folder it just keep popping the "How do you want to open" window.. I thing it is a permission related issue..