# Run any possible Powershell script with a space in path

Tags: powershell, path, directory, space

I'm experiencing a very strange behavior of PowerShell on my PC.
I'm trying to run a script (doesn't matter what's in the script) from a path with a space in it.
For example, this one:

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$User1 = Read-Host "Enter User to copy Group-Memberships from"
$User2 = Read-Host "Enter User to past Group-Memberships to"
Get-ADUser -Identity $User1 -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $User2 -PassThru | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName
```

When I'm running it from within ISE or from a previously opened PowerShell Windows it's working fine. But it immediately crashes if I'm trying to just double-click the .ps1-File. It opens a PowerShell-Windows, displays an Error-Message I had to capture with a screen recording tool because it's gone only a fraction of a second later. The Error-Message is saying:

> C:\Users###\Desktop\Member : The term 'C:\Users###\Desktop\Member' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   
>     At line:1 char:1
>   
>     + C:\Users###\Desktop\Member of\Copy_AD_Member-of_DomainLocal.ps1
>   
>     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           
> + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users###\Desktop\Member:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>           
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

So as you can see, the Path to the script is "C:\Users###\Desktop\Member of\Copy_AD_Member-of_DomainLocal.ps1", with a single space in the scripts parant directory "Member of".

As soon as I replace the space with a dash it's working fine.

My target originally was to make the script runnable even if you move it to another directory and without typing any line of code manually as a user. Is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: Why don't you use the [call operator (&)](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) instead of double-clicking and running it. Will save a lot of fuss!

Comment: Yeah, but I'll have to put the call operator in a script to, soo...

Comment: I kinda don't get the issue here, cause I was able to run scripts with a space in the path on another PC before, this is making me crazy

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-any-way-to-make-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-ps1-file) where one of the answer suggests that `one of PowerShell's security features is that users can NOT launch script with a double click`. You can try one from the proposed solutions.

Comment: Okay :o This "security feature" is a very new one then, is it? It's annoying...

Comment: I don't think so. Historically ps1 have never had double click associations in the registry. This is to prevent proliferation of malware. vbs was the same.  What I suspect is that you enabled this (on purpose or not) with a .reg file or something akin to that with a plugin. It's not implemented correctly to account for space. So, if you want this to work, you have to edit that value and quote it.. `.... '%1'` or something like that. I think Viveks linked post would help point you.

Comment: No it was already there. See `Get-Help about_Command_Precedence` in your PowerShell console for more info!

Comment: Hm okay... So the only "easy to use"-way to make a .ps1-File runnable via double-click is to make sure the path doesn't have any spaces in it OR using a shortcut, where I have to manually edit the path to the script anyway, is that correct?

Comment: And something like this in the shortcut's target is not possible, is it?      
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& '.\Get_AD_Member-of.ps1'"

Comment: My target originally was to make the script runnable even if you move it to another directory and without typing any line of code manually as a user.

Comment: *So the only "easy to use"-way to make a .ps1-File runnable via double-click is to make sure the path doesn't have any spaces in it OR using a shortcut, where I have to manually edit the path to the script anyway, is that correct?* No. What gave you that idea? Make sure that the parameter for the file argument is properly quoted (`"%1"`) in the file association in the registry.

Comment: Yeah, but that's no "easy to use"-way if you have to make sure that this is Setup for every PC in the company...

Comment: Yes, it is. It's one registry setting that can easily be deployed via group policies.