# How do I execute a powershell script by a shortcut key?

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut

So I have successfully bound a key to open this script:

[image: shortcut settings]

But the way to run that script with PowerShell is to right-click it and go `Open with PowerShell`. Using the key binding, it just opens it normally (so with notepad).

How can I make it so it opens with PowerShell from that binding?

Answer (score 5):

You already have a `lnk` that points to your script file. Make that point to PowerShell and pass your file as a parameter. Assuming your file is located in `C:\PSScripts` you would have to set the Target of the `lnk` to

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "& C:\PSScripts\Display Off.ps1" -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `General` tab in your shortcut settings, and change the `Open with` row from `notepad` to

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't run PS script, because security feature. User can't double click it.
You can create simple .bat like:

```
powershell -command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned 
powershell -command Your Script
powershell -command Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

Check too this topic: [Is there a way to make a PowerShell script work by double clicking a .ps1 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-a-ps1-file)
There are more solutions there.