# How to open .pas file in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to open a free pascal or turbo pascal file that has a .pas extension from a wpf application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 4):

If you want to `open` the editor associated with a file, then just do:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

Where `path` is the [FQN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) of the `.pas` file.

Basically, Windows will look for a program that is registered to view/edit the type (extension) of file when its not an executable.  It will then create a new process passing the file name to the viewer/editor. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859 for more info.

**OR if by `open`**, you mean making your WPF application the default program associated with `.pas` files.  Then you need to make a few registry changes. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application) provides the details.

**OR if by `open`**, you mean reading the file, then try `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` or `System.IO.File.ReadAllText`.  More info at [File method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File_methods(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: By open I mean "open the editor associated" , so it was the first one ,thanks for your help

Comment: there is no `File.ReadAllTextLines` - there's `File.ReadAllText` and `File.ReadAllLines` though

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\input.pas");
```

For more information about `File` class, have a look at the resource here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

May be below code would help

```
 using System.IO;

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\input.pas", FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but when try this "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);" I get what I want