# How to make wpf file activation?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

So for the previous hours i've been looking on how to do and all i've found is UWP solutions that doesn't work with the tutorials i've found.

I am making an application that read a specific format (Some Json and other put together). Those file are readable by my app, no problems.

To push forward the application i'd like to make that the files to be opened by my app with a single double-click like Acrobat open the .pdf.

For now I have no code because no idea on where the work has to be done. If you have a solution or part of a solution post it and i'll update the post if needed.

As information the file format is .glf

Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Vista generate the icon for documents associated to my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580827/how-does-vista-generate-the-icon-for-documents-associated-to-my-application)

Answer (score 1):

[Associate a file extension](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-change-file-associations/) with your app in Windows, override the `OnStartup` method of your `App.xaml` and check the value of the `StartupEventArgs.Args` parameter. It should contain the path to the file and it's then the responsibility of your app to handle it.

[Associate a file extension with WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098705/associate-a-file-extension-with-wpf-application)

[Making my application to be the default one to open all .txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25859676/making-my-application-to-be-the-default-one-to-open-all-txt-files)

Comment: @XimazeC: Does this answer your question?