# How to add my c# application in Open with list programmatically?

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

I want add my c# application in "Open With" of xml extension during the setup of application.
Is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application