# How to register your application in the open with of .jpg extension

Tags: c#, installshield, regedit

I want to register my c# application in the open with menu of .jpg.
I tried to create a registry key, but was not able to.

Edit: I need a registry file which I can use in the Install Shield setup of my application to register the application as a open with option of .jpg file extension

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associate File Extension with Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application)

Comment: Yeah it is kind of a duplicate but the said post gives method if not Installation file is created, but I want a regedit code ".reg" file which can register my application in the open with menu of ".jpg" files

Comment: How to write an extension registration file for importing in the registry is very well documented on the web. If you have that, show it in your question and explain what isn't working.

Comment: http://www.technorms.com/26760/add-remove-programs-open-menu-registry

I was following this guide but as you see, the openwith list of any extension has got letters for name, i could not write a registry key for it because i did not get how to use a variable.