# Associate File Extension with Application depending on OS version

Tags: c#, windows, file-association

Is there a universal (all windows OS) way to associate a custom extension to a new program for the current user on windows ? (coded in c#)

The closest solution I found is here: [Associate File Extension with Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application)

but it does not seem to work for windows 8.1

Comment: What does *does not seem to work* mean? Was the application that made the change an x86 or x64 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put a solution here for windows 10: [Associate File Extension with Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application)

It can be easily adapted by creating missing node such as ApplicationAssociationToasts.