# File Association for my own Visual Basic application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2010, registry

I made my application that can read some specific extension on load in Visual Basic 2017.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1).ToString = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString + "\" + My.Application.Info.AssemblyName + ".exe" Then

        Else
            If System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)) = ".myOwnExt" Then
                Dim fileReader As String
                fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1).ToString)
                MsgBox(fileReader)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

But I want to make my program default for that extension and I want to set my icon for those files. Is it possible to make it happen with Visual Basic?

Comment: This is something you would do in Windows (or whatever operating system you are using)

Comment: Perhaps something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application

Comment: That's C# and I don't understand it

Comment: Just run it through http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: It's full of errors

Comment: The term you are looking for is File Association.  Gobs of posts here to create them in code, with a .REG file, via an installer or manually.  There is no need to check for the extension in code - when the user opens a file with your properly registered extension, Windows will start your app and send the while file name on the as a command line arg.

Comment: @Plutonix I know that but I didn't want other extensions to be opened with my app. I know that something similar to DWRoelands answer might work but he didn't explain anything and his code does not work, so I want someone to answer properly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code would look something like this...

```
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".myOwnExt").SetValue("", _
          "myOwnExt", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)     
My.Computer.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("MyProgramName\shell\open\command").SetValue("", _
          Application.ExecutablePath & " ""%l"" ", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.String)
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I want my program to be default for opening `.myOwnExt` It only shows error when I open it through file

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example on how to do this in VB .NET. Like mentioned above you need to change some registry settings.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18594/File-Association-in-VB-NET

On a quick glance at your code `GetCommandLineArgs(1)` needs to be changed to `GetCommandLineArgs(0)` to get this working.