# how to retrieve saved file opened from wpf application

Tags: wpf

My application is in WPF. Application based on video editing, so I am saving the project as a .xml format. And when I double click the saved file, it does not opened in my wpf application. I want to open the saved file in my application when the user double click the saved file icon. Is it possible? I searched the solution, but I didn't get any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS this is for.  You need to do one of two things:

1) Change the file association for the .xml type (On windows 10 this is a little more complicated)

or

2) Change your own file type to something else and create a new file association for it. This would be the preferred way.

[Answer from previous question/post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-applicationhttp://)