# Create File Association in c# 8

Tags: c#, .net, file, visual-studio-2019

I'm making an application that I need to create a file association with a specficic extension (*.xpkg) the problem is that I don't find the exactly code to do this. If anyone know a way for create a file association easy in c# please tell me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2697804/1862812

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Associate File Extension with Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application)

Comment: File associations are very well documented. There are a lot of articles that show how this works. The best place to create a file association is in the program's installer, not the program itself. All installers support this.