# C# wpf open serialized file with windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I've a custom file. Serialization and deserialization is working
fine when using my custom functions

- File > Save
- File > Open

When I'm going directly in the windows explorer on my file
and want to open it with the program it's not deserializing.
How can I handle the deserialization from "outside"?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you do "open with..." in windows, the path of the file will be an argument to your `Main` function. You can get some ideas here, I guess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088961/handle-program-being-opened-by-open-with (also check the linked duplicate) . It's up to you to properly read the argument given in main, and act accordingly in your program (for instance, directly call the deserialization function you have)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a file is opened from Windows Explorer with your app, the absolute path of the file is passed as the first command line argument.
In case of WPF, you can handle the `Startup` event of `App` to intercept such an argument for later opening in `MainWindow`.

```
// App.xaml.cs
public string FileToOpen;

public App()
{
    Startup += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Args.Length > 0)
            FileToOpen = e.Args[0];
    };
}
```

```cs
// MainWindow.xaml.cs
public MainWindow()
{
    var path = (Application.Current as App).FileToOpen;
    if (path != null)
    {
        // TODO: open the file when appropriate
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked fine. Do you know how it is possible how to find out whether the app is already opened? Because when it is and I open a file with the explorer, I'll get a new instance of my app. That's a bit annoying.

Comment: Yes, but that's another question.