# Registry Association Problem

Tags: c#, .net, registry, exe

I have a my own file type .Has and a program HasEditor which i want to be Default program for my file type. but when i right click on the has file select open with and browse to HasEditor.exe it just attaches internet explorer insteat of HasEditor.exe.

What exactly happens is strange when i double click HasEditor.exe its icon doesnt appear in the open with dialog.

any suggestions will be appreciated.
HasEditor is my own app made in c#.net

Comment: Could you be more elaborate please? Provide some code where you are handling the file in your program or so. Cause that would be more easier for us to detect the problem. Problem description like this won't help us to resolve.

Comment: Anindya, 
The issue is not of code the app is running fine, its just that the open with dialog in Win 7 wont display it and i select it as defalut program for .Has files

Comment: then your question's tags should be modified. It's no way related to .Net or C#, right?

Comment: yes Mr.Chatterjee you are right. the tag police caught me.

Answer (score 0):

Have at look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212906/script-to-associate-an-extension-to-a-program#212921) question which will allow you to set up the association programmatically. Maybe doing this will fix the problem?

Comment: thanks for the link but i do not want to it programmatically i want the user to do manual attachment using the open with dialog in win 7.

Comment: Ok in that case is your icon for your program the correct size for the 'open with' dialog? It could be that it requires it in a different size and that's what is causing the problem. Also I assume your program is a windows app and not a web app?

Comment: i just tried this in vista seems to be working there and icon is appearing. but the problem seems to be only in win7

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Does it appear properly everywhere else (eg the executable itself, top left of the app when it is running etc)?

Comment: yup its running perfectly fine there

Comment: Ok in that case I'd try changing the icon to one you know should display properly (ie the default application icon) and see if it still has the problem. If it does you know it's something to do with windows and the 'open with' dialog, if it doesn't then you know it's something to do with the icon. Once you know either way you can try some more specific things to fix it.