# how to open all *.xml files on my computer by my C# program?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

i made C# program that open and show xml files.

how to make (on my program installation) that all *.xml files

that in my computer will opened with my program ?

thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761/how-to-associate-a-file-extension-to-the-current-executable-in-c

Comment: Do you want to do it programatically (when installing your application, etc)? or just do it once in your computer manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associate File Extension with Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212906/script-to-associate-an-extension-to-a-program#212921), you need to change the value of the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xmlfile\shell\open\command` on the user's machine.

This could be achieved programatically by code such as (untested):

```
// Get App Executable path
string appPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

RegistryKey rkShellOpen = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"xmlfile\shell\open", true);
rkShellOpen.SetValue("command", appPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he is wanting a way to search the hard drive for all xml files, so that he can then manage them in some sort of tree for easy opening and closing.

You could do something similar to this...

```
   void RecursiveDirectorySearch(string sDir, string patternToMatch) 
        {
          // Where sDir would be the drive you want to search, I.E. "C:\"
          // Where patternToMatch has the extension, I.E. ".xml"
            try 
            {
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
                    {
                       if(f.Contains(patternToMatch)
                        {
                          lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
                        }
                    }
                    DirSearch(d);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }
        }
```