# Detect the Acrobat installation or any alternate way to open PDF

Tags: wpf, pdf, user-controls

i have built a WPF application to view the PDF files using `Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll`, the problem is if the Adobe Acrobat reader is not installed on the client machine the application `stops working` and crashes.

Is there a way i can detect the Acrobat Reader installation before hand and then at the run time include the reference to the `Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll` other-wise show an error message?

OR

are there any better open source solutions available to display pdf files in WPF?

Regards.

Comment: any suggestions, ideas? please share...

Comment: I'm not too familiar with COM interop, but shouldn't your application only crash when you actually *invoke* one of the methods from `Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll`? This certainly is the case for P/Invoke methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any PDF capable app is properly installed then `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\MyPDF.pdf");` start it with your PDF file...

As for detection you can check the registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Adobe...` for the Reader and/or Acrobat.

Another option would be to check for registered file association - on how check this SO answer [Script to associate an extension to a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212906/script-to-associate-an-extension-to-a-program/212921#212921)

**EDIT - as per comment:**

For a scenario where you need to "dynamically" use Interop adding the reference statically is not a good idea... an alternative way is to do COM the "old-fashoined way" using something similar to the following:

```
object A = Activator.CreateInstance (Type.GetTypeFromProgId (""));
object R = Type.GetTypeFromProgId ("").InvokeMember ("MyMethodName", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, A, new object[] {myParam1, myParam2});
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject (A);
```

Relevant links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hss5hw09.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx

Comment: tnx for the reply, can you please tell me after determining that whether Adobe Acrobat is installed or not how can i add reference to `Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll` in my project

Answer (score 1):

If any app/soft. is installed in Windows, using a installer, it generally creates a entry in Installed programs seen in control panel (i.e. in registry). So you can search for it, as `Adobe Reader` mostly comes in a installer and check validate the installation of `Adobe reader`.

For reference see [artice1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/installed_programs.aspx) [article2](http://www.thereforesystems.com/get-a-list-of-installed-applications-using-linq-and-c/)

Answer (score 0):

Check for GUID in component services. Usually adobe reader has the same COM GUID.
Check for installation. Is it available on c:\Program Files\Adobe .... or c:\Program Files x86\Adobe.... This is assume that adobe is installed on that folder. This is the light way to do.
I search for file name AcroRd32.exe using:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", AcroRd32.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

if it is found, then you can check that the installation of adobe reader is OK or not.

You can call adobe pdf I using Process.Start and capture its exception and then kill its process.
If it is throw exception then adobe reader is not installed or corrupted. otherwise it is installed

eg:

```
try
{
Process.Start(@"c:\your program files\Adobe\Adobe.exe");
} catch
{
   throw new Exception ("adobe is not installed or error");
}
```

You can customize above code by searching adobe reader file and then passed it into Process.Start parameter.

I dunno open source solution to display pdf using wpf. sorry

Comment: -1 Sorry, this probably the worst way to do this. In the day and age of 3+TB hard drives, searching the entire disk for an executable can take minutes. Also you should be using the `%ProgramFiles%` and `ProgramFiles(x86)` environment variables. Finally the user can always choose to install Adobe in a completely different location. Instead do use the registry, that's what it was built for.