# In Powershell django-install.py not recognized. Already added Scripts directory to PATH

Tags: python, django

This happened to me on multiple machines already... typing `django-admin.py startproject test` yields the `The term 'django-admin.py' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet....` error, while trying to call on any other module or script in the python Scripts folder works...

Typing `python [Scripts path]\django-admin.py startproject test` works perfectly, so does copying `django-admin.py` to my working directory... it just won't call it straight up.

I've been googling for a while and it seems like this problem is always people not having Scripts added in their PATH. I did, however. Is there something else I am missing? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the association so what Windows knows that .py extension files are supposed to be run with the Python application?

[Script to associate an extension to a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212906/script-to-associate-an-extension-to-a-program)

Comment: Yes I've encountered another open question that address this issue. Although this seems to be pertinent after the shell finds the `.py` file. I can't find the post right now but in the question the poster reports seeing the windows prompt being open of which program to use for the `.py` file

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to django not being in your PATH variable properly.  I'll play around with it more later, but in the mean time a quick fix is just to call it directly:

C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject YourProjectName

(this will be different with Python3 obviously).

Worked for me, and so I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows where you can edit PATH, under this you have PATHEXT. At the end, add `.PY` so PowerShell will know that .py files are executable.

Comment: Specifically, add `;.PY` to the end of PATHEXT in the lower half of the dialog found under the Environment button in the Advanced tab of System Properties, reachable with Win+Break.