# How can I open a text file with my executable?

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, text

I want to right-click on a text file and "Open With..." it with my own program, but I can't find any information on how to do that. I want to make my program in C++ or with WinForms (C#).
I want to open that file and to use my program as an interpreter on a small "homemade programming language", so I want to pass the data from the file directly to my program.
Can anyone help me?
*hope I'm clear enough on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You want to associate the file types …

Comment: For C++ I can help you, by recommending one of these [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: For c++ you want to handle command line arguments. the file name will be passed as the first argument to your c++ application when using the Open With from Explorer. [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/)

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but I already found how to do that. Only needed to add string[] args in the main function and from there the things are easy.

Comment: You must prefer a single language for a single question. Either C++ or C#, both are different languages. In the other hand, you need to show your efforts what you've done so far.

Comment: @PaulT. : If you use c#, this link may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application

Comment: @PaulT. : Have a look at this too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212906/script-to-associate-an-extension-to-a-program#212921

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm a new user. And also thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just gonna to answer your Question for C#. If you still need C++ support you can tell me.

**Option 1 - Drop down:**

So if you for example create a Console-Application in C# (Visual Studio), it will look like this:

[image]

As you can see in the Picture: the Program accepts Arguments (`args` String Array)
If you drag & drop your file on your .exe, the filepath of the file you dropped will be saved in the `args` String Array. Now you can read the file (for example with the File-Class).

**Option 2 - Right Click -> Open with my Program:**

For that, you can simply add a new entry in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` (Windows Registry) to register you Program as a "Right Click Menu Program".
Here is a detailed How-To:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/

After you added your Program to the Windows Registry you can proceed as shown in Option 1 (`args`).

Any more questions? Let me know.

Greets
Bennet

**EDIT:** 
Sorry, didnt really read the comments :D but i guess your Question is answered. I will let this stay here for future readers which dont read the comments either ;)

Comment: Thanks for  your answer.